# download multiple files using SimpleFTPSample

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I've been trying to figure out how to download multiple files in a row based on the SimpleFTPSample provided by apple. Basically, I'm filtering what the user can see when they browse an ftp server, but when they select a certain file type, I want it to automatically check for another file of the same name with a different extension and if it exists, download it as well. I can't seem to get this second file to download no matter what I do. It seems strange because if I select two files in a row in my tableview, it downloads both of them just fine. Any ideas?

#### Edit:

It's just the SimpleFTPSample from apple.developer.com, all I did was create additional NSInputStream and NSOutputStream objects and I created a new _startReceiveFile method that gets called from _startReceive if I'm downloading a file instead of getting a directory listing. _startReceiveFile is the same code for _startReceive in the file download code for the sample project, except if the file to download has a certain extension, it also downloads an additional file with the additional stream objects. Let me know if I need to clarify more or try to put together a clear example.

Comment: Is there any code that you think may be appropriate to show us? That would help us to analyze your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since there were no takers, I'll just post my solution here. I've abandoned trying to download two files at once. Instead, I just keep the ftp browsing window open and only handle the opening of the file once both files have been downloaded (user has clicked on each one separately). It's not what I wanted, but it will work, at least until I can figure out how to get two files with one request.